# Junit tests work in Eclipse, but fail when run through Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, ant

```
<project name = "HK" default = "test" basedir = ".">
<property name = "srcdir" location = "src" />
<property name = "testdir" location = "testclasses" />
<property name="libdir" value="lib" />
<path id = "classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="${libdir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="clean" description="Removes previous build">
    <delete dir="${testdir}" />
</target>


<target name="compile" description="Compiles java source code">

    <mkdir dir="${testdir}" />
    <javac srcdir="${srcdir}" destdir="${testdir}"  debug="true" classpathref="classpath.test" includeantruntime="false"/>
</target>


<target name = "test" depends = "compile">


    <junit  printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes" description="yes" failureproperty="true">
        <classpath location="${libdir}/junit4.jar" />
        <classpath location="${libdir}/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
        <classpath location = "${testdir}/adviceTest"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name = "TestRunner" todir="./junitreport" />
    </junit>

</target>

<target name="junitreport" description="Create a report for the rest result">
    <junitreport todir="./junitreport">
        <fileset dir="./junitreport">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="./junithtml/html" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

The Junit tests work when I run them in eclipse, but fail when I run them through ant (either run through eclipse or terminal); they each throw the following exception:

```
TestRunner.class

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestRunner.class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

Comment: This is a classpath problem.

Comment: classpath all are correct only @duffymo

Comment: No Eclipse and Ant class paths are different. That's why one works and the other fails.

Comment: all .class files are generating in the following path through ANT; ${testdir}/adviceTest  that one only i mentioned here. <classpath location = "${testdir}/adviceTest"/>

Comment: I guess it's perfect then. Good luck.